# How i can clone my the git repository using Python and PyGithub/GitPython?

Tags: python, gitpython

Here I was looking around write some code through which I can maintain my git repository.

I am python beginners level but i know it. My repository on git hub is.

```
https://github.com/gtrdotmcs/NewDjango/
```

I would really like to clone,pull,commit and push my repository using python code.

Yeah it not easy for beginners but I would really like to do it.
Coming around i came with some python libraries for github. 
[PyGithub](http://jacquev6.github.io/PyGithub/)
and [GitPython](http://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.1/tutorial.html)

I would also like to know which is better one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[PyGithub](http://jacquev6.github.io/PyGithub/) is a library for interacting with the GitHub API; it will not let you clone your repository or otherwise interact with a local git repository.

[GitPython](http://pythonhosted.org/GitPython/0.3.1/tutorial.html) is a Python interface to `git` and can be used to clone a remote repository.  In fact, there's an example of exactly that at the beginning of the tutorial to which you have linked.

That said, it's not clear from your question exactly what you hope to accomplish -- learning the `git` commandline interface is an important skill if you're going to be working with GitHub (or `git` in general).  While you can probably perform many of the same tasks with `GitPython`, you are arguably going to be spending much of your time duplicating the existing functionality of the commandline tools.

Comment: thanks for clearing me between these tow library. yes u were right i might duplicate my work but i am looking fwd to write an app for my django project. it is initial stage but i will like in feature. i was making my idea cleared will i be able to do tha